# Exception of Backgroundworker Progress

Tags: c#, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I used the Backgroundworker to display progress when exporting data to excel. But exeption happen related to Thread. Here is my code:

```
    public frmPLANNING()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lblStatus.Text = string.Empty;
            backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
            backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
        }
private void tbrExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Minimum;

                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {            
            SqlConnection cnn;
            var ssqltable = "PLANNING";
            string sql = null;
            string data = null;
            var i = 0;
            var j = 0;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
            Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = Missing.Value;
            xlApp = new Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            cnn = new SqlConnection(strConStr);
            cnn.Open();
            sql = "SELECT * From " + ssqltable;
            var dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            dscmd.Fill(ds);           
                foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
                {
                    for (var i1 = 0; i1 < dt.Columns.Count; i1++)
                    {
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, i1 + 1] = dt.Columns[i1].ColumnName;
                    }
                }
                for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {                   
                    var s = i + 1;

                    for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                    {
                        data = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[s + 1, j + 1].EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "@";

                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[s + 1, j + 1] = data;
                        var _totalProgress = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count-1;

                        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i * 100 / _totalProgress);
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(100);  
            }                      
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                xlWorkBook.SaveAs(savePath);
                xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
                xlApp.Quit();
                releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
                releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
                releaseObject(xlApp);              
                MessageBox.Show("PLANNING_EXCEL_Template.xlsx  file has been created!");
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
            {
                lblStatus.Text = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
                progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {           
            lblStatus.Text = "Task completed!";
        }
```

And this is the exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadStateException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process.

Answer (score 0):

Excel automation requires that you create and use your `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application` and related objects in a particular way:

- They must be used in the thread where they are originally created, and
- That thread must be an single-threaded apartment (STA) thread.

Put another way, you need to treat the Excel objects the same way you treat your UI objects. Make sure they are created in the main UI thread (which is already STA), and use `Control.Invoke()` or similar to make sure any code that accesses those objects is executed in that main UI thread.

You can still use the `BackgroundWorker`, or whatever worker thread paradigm you like, to handle the SQL queries. But you'll need to make sure that the results are passed off to a delegate invoked on the main UI thread, where they can then be copied into the Excel data objects.

Comment: Could you help me where can I correct this problem with code? It raised error at : if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that shows where `saveFileDialog1` is created. But, if you create that in the main UI thread, then it needs to remain there. It would have to follow the same rules as the Excel object, i.e. use `Control.Invoke()` or similar to execute that code. It seems to me an appropriate place to put that code would be in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler you already have.

Comment: I moved  if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                xlWorkBook.SaveAs(savePath);
                xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
                xlApp.Quit();
                releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
                releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
                releaseObject(xlApp);              
                MessageBox.Show("PLANNING_EXCEL_Template.xlsx  file has been created!");
            } to RunWorkerCompleted and problem seem to be solved but ProgressBar run 2 loop (2 time when reaching 100%) . Any idea?

Comment: Lacking a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to know for sure what the problem is. But usually, problems having the form of "when using `BackgroundWorker`, works seems to be done two or more times" turn out to be that the `DoWork` event is subscribed more than once (e.g. in the Designer and then again in code, or just in the code but once for every time the command is executed, so each time the command is executed, the number of times the work is done increases by one).

Comment: The code you show above certainly could have that bug. Try either only subscribing all the event handlers in the Designer, or create a new `BackgroundWorker` object each time you run the command.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Just remove :

```
 backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
```